# regarding running the tutorial example for tf.contrib.learn

Tags: tensorflow

When following the example given in [tf.contrib.learn Quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/tflearn/index.html), the following error message was generated

```
Trace back (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
training_set =    
tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
                                                   target_dtype=np.int)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datasets'
```

What might be the reason causing this type of error? Does that mean that Tensorflow was not installed correctly?

Comment: maybe you have an old version? I tried in 0.10rc0 and the module is there

Comment: How to check the version of tensorflow having been installaed

Comment: tf.__version__              k

Comment: I have the same issue: Mine is In [3]: tf.__version__ 
Out[3]: '0.11.0rc0' . I get the error : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_csv'